# GPU upgrade from GTX 980 to Titan Z and code changes in cuda

Tags: cuda, gpu, upgrade, hardware

I am planning to purchase a Titan Z as per the requirement of my project. I am currently using GTX 980.

So for the upgrade, are any code changes required or the same code would work fine? if so, please mention what amendments are required

Also, the base clock is more in Titan X, so is it a better option than Titan Z?

Comment: @Roy the measure on that website is for graphics, not compute, so isn't very meaningful. That said, the Titan Z is an older GPU, based off an older architecture. The Titan X would probably be a better option.

Comment: @Jez Whoops I didn't see that. My bad.  Thanks

Comment: Support for multi-GPU, unless already implemented, will be the biggest change.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Titan Z has 2 GPUs, and sharing data between then is time consuming. It does have more cores but titan X has way better base clock. For that and considering the cost, I would go for Titan X.

I don't know about the compatibility though.